# Как сделать чтобы текст не менял прозрачность при наведении, а картинка меняла

Tags: html, css

Нужно чтобы текст не менял прозрачность, а фон меня при наведении

```css
*, ::before, ::after {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: none;
}

body {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 1080px;
}

.container {
    max-width: 1400px;
}

.header {
    margin: 20px 0 0 0;
}

.header__list {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
}

.header__btn {
    border: 2px solid black;
    background-color: transparent;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.header__btn:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.main {
    margin: 60px;
}

.main__body {
    display: flex;
    gap: 0;
}

.main__block {
    width: 756.57px;
    height: 530px;
    background: green;
    transition: 0.5s; /* Добавляем анимацию перехода для прозрачности */
    position: relative;
}

.main__block:hover{
    opacity: 0.7;
}

.main__block-content-wrap {
    display: block;
}

.main__block-siteName {
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding: 20px 0 0 15px;
}

.main__block-toggle {
    max-width: 144px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: rgba(21, 21, 21, 1);
}

.main__toggle-text {
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    padding: 6px 16px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/style.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&family=Playfair+Display:wght@800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header class="header">
        <nav class="header-body">
            <div class="container">
                <ul class="header__list">
                    <li class="header__item"><button href="" class="header__btn">Все</button></li>
                    <li class="header__item"><button href="" class="header__btn">Реализованные</button></li>
                    <li class="header__item"><button href="" class="header__btn">Плановые</button></li>
                    <li class="header__item"><button href="" class="header__btn">Сданые</button></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <main class="main">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="main__body">
                <div class="main__block main__block1">
                    <div class="main__block-content-wrap">
                        <p class="main__block-siteName">ЖК Солнечный</p>
                        <div class="main__block-toggle"><p class="main__toggle-text">Реализован</p></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="main__block main__block2">
                    <div class="main__block-content-wrap">
                        <p class="main__block-siteName">ЖК Солнечный</p>
                        <div class="main__block-toggle"><p class="main__toggle-text">Реализован</p></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="main__body">
                <div class="main__block main__block3">
                    <div class="main__block-content-wrap">
                        <p class="main__block-siteName">ЖК Солнечный</p>
                        <div class="main__block-toggle"><p class="main__toggle-text">Реализован</p></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="main__block main__block4">
                    <div class="main__block-content-wrap">
                        <p class="main__block-siteName">ЖК Солнечный</p>
                        <div class="main__block-toggle"><p class="main__toggle-text">Реализован</p></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
<script src="./scripts/script.js"></script>
<script>
    AOS.init();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё потому что вы задаете opacity всему блоку, из-за чего и такое происходит, чтобы избежать этого можно создать дополнительный блок фона с `position: absolute` и размерами 100% по ширине и высоте. Ну и при наведении менять прозрачность данного блока.

```css
*,
 ::before,
 ::after {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: none;
}

body {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 1080px;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1400px;
}

.header {
  margin: 20px 0 0 0;
}

.header__list {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}

.header__btn {
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.header__btn:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.main {
  margin: 60px;
}

.main__body {
  display: flex;
  gap: 0;
}

.main__block {
  width: 756.57px;
  height: 530px;
  /* Нижние два стиля переходят на блок фона */
  /* background: green; */
  /* transition: 0.5s; */
  /* Добавляем анимацию перехода для прозрачности */
  position: relative;
}

.main__block:hover {
  /* opacity: 0.7; */
  /* Убираем и это тоже */
}

.main__block-bg {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
  transition: 0.5s;
  z-index: -1;
}


/* При наведении на main__block, меняем стили блока фона */

.main__block:hover .main__block-bg {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.main__block-content-wrap {
  display: block;
}

.main__block-siteName {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 20px 0 0 15px;
}

.main__block-toggle {
  max-width: 144px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(21, 21, 21, 1);
}

.main__toggle-text {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  padding: 6px 16px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/style.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&family=Playfair+Display:wght@800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header class="header">
    <nav class="header-body">
      <div class="container">
        <ul class="header__list">
          <li class="header__item"><button href="" class="header__btn">Все</button></li>
          <li class="header__item"><button href="" class="header__btn">Реализованные</button></li>
          <li class="header__item"><button href="" class="header__btn">Плановые</button></li>
          <li class="header__item"><button href="" class="header__btn">Сданые</button></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <main class="main">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="main__body">
        <div class="main__block main__block1">

          <!-- Блок с фоном -->
          <div class="main__block-bg"></div>

          <div class="main__block-content-wrap">
            <p class="main__block-siteName">ЖК Солнечный</p>
            <div class="main__block-toggle">
              <p class="main__toggle-text">Реализован</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="main__block main__block2">

          <!-- Блок с фоном -->
          <div class="main__block-bg"></div>

          <div class="main__block-content-wrap">
            <p class="main__block-siteName">ЖК Солнечный</p>
            <div class="main__block-toggle">
              <p class="main__toggle-text">Реализован</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="main__body">
        <div class="main__block main__block3">

          <!-- Блок с фоном -->
          <div class="main__block-bg"></div>

          <div class="main__block-content-wrap">
            <p class="main__block-siteName">ЖК Солнечный</p>
            <div class="main__block-toggle">
              <p class="main__toggle-text">Реализован</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="main__block main__block4">

          <!-- Блок с фоном -->
          <div class="main__block-bg"></div>

          <div class="main__block-content-wrap">
            <p class="main__block-siteName">ЖК Солнечный</p>
            <div class="main__block-toggle">
              <p class="main__toggle-text">Реализован</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
  <script src="./scripts/script.js"></script>
  <script>
    AOS.init();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, очень помогли

Comment: Пожалуйста, был рад помочь :)